# How to plot a shapefile centered in the Pacific with Basemap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

When plotting with **Basemap's readshapefile**, if the defined map is centered anywhere else than the longitudinal center of the shapefile, only a portion of it it's plotted. Here's an example using [Natural Earth's](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-physical-vectors/) coastlines:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

shpf = './NaturalEarth/ne_50m_land/ne_50m_land'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, dpi=100)

m = Basemap(
    ax = ax,
    projection = 'cyl',
    llcrnrlon = 0, llcrnrlat = -90,
    urcrnrlon = 360, urcrnrlat = 90
) 

m.readshapefile(shpf,'ne_50m_land')

m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,45),labels=[True,False,False,True])
```

Which produces:

[image: Image output]

Is there a workaround for this with Basemap or Python? I know some people re-center the shapefile in QGIS or similar, but it seems unpractical to do so every time you create a new map, and my QGIS skills are extremely basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to tell `readshapefile` not to plot the coastlines directly and then to manipulate the line segments before plotting them yourself. Here an example based on your use case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

shpf = 'shapefiles/ne_50m_land'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, dpi=100)

m = Basemap(
    ax = ax,
    projection = 'cyl',
    llcrnrlon = 0, llcrnrlat = -90,
    urcrnrlon = 360, urcrnrlat = 90
) 

m.readshapefile(shpf,'ne_50m_land', drawbounds = False)

boundary = 0.0

for info, shape in zip(m.ne_50m_land_info, m.ne_50m_land):
    lons, lats = map(np.array, zip(*shape))

    sep = (lons <= boundary).astype(int)
    roots = np.where(sep[:-1]+sep[1:] == 1)[0]+1
    lower = np.concatenate([[0],roots]).astype(int)
    upper = np.concatenate([roots,[len(lons)]]).astype(int)

    for low, high in zip(lower,upper):
        lo_patch = lons[low:high]
        la_patch = lats[low:high]
        lo_patch[lo_patch<0] += 360
        x,y = m(lo_patch,la_patch)
        ax.plot(x,y,'k',lw=0.5)

m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,45),labels=[True,False,False,True])

plt.show()
```

In the example above, I iterate through the line segments of the shape file the way it is explained in the [Basemap documentation](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shapefile.html). First I thought it would be enough to just add 360 to each point with a longitude smaller 0, but then you would get horizontal lines whenever a coast line crosses the 0 degree line. So, instead, one has to cut the lines into smaller segments whenever such a crossing appears. This is quite easily accomplished with `numpy`. I then use the `plot` command to draw the coast lines. If you want to do something more complex have a look at the [Basemap documentation](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shapefile.html).

The final result looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

Hope this helps.