# weird horizontal lines on maps

Tags: python, maps, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to draw the world map of storm form 1945 to 2017 but every time the final image would have some weird horizontal lines (shown in the picture below) which make it unusable.

anyone knows what's going on? please give me some advice how I could remove those lines.

Thank you very much

https://pasteboard.co/HyiElwe.png

[image]

Comment: why I cannot attach the image??

Comment: I think only new users cannot attach images until you've accumulated some rep. but that will work

Comment: thank you for your comment, I just attached link to the image

Comment: does your code use `matplotlib.pyplot.hlines()` or `matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline()`?

Comment: Are these storms that are going around the other side of the world? Left to right? And it is plotting across the world? My best guess. Try to wrap the coordinates around the earth.

Comment: yes you are correct but how do I wrap the coordinates around the earth.

Comment: can you guy see the image I uploaded?

Comment: @davedwards I dont use any of the 2 in my code @@

Comment: We can see the image fine, thanks. As for wrapping... I guess end the trace if it hits on extreme and start it again at the other side? Or instead of connecting the points, just make lots of dots or dashes that are close enough to look connected.

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51021870/2454357) I was solving a different problem, but encountered the same problem with traces that wrap around the edge of the map. See if this helps. If not, please provide some code.